# Facebook login doesn't start second activity if app is not installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement the Facebook Login on an Android app. I followed the Facebook Developer guide and it's working but if Facebook app is not installed then it takes login details,logs in and stays on same activity and just show logout button, if I close application and start again then it works perfectly fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        isLoggedIn();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken   accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                nextActivity(profile);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");



    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        //Facebook login
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    }

    public void isLoggedIn() {

        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken!=null) {

            Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            nextActivity(profile);
        }
    }

    private void nextActivity(Profile profile) {
        if (profile != null) {                                                                                        Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
            main.putExtra("Name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("Surname", profile.getLastName());
            startActivity(main);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using  `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback()` use `loginButton.registerCallback()`

**EDIT:**

Inside onSuccess have following code:

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                               this.stopTracking();
                               nextActivity(currentProfile);
                        }
                };
                profileTracker.startTracking();
        }else{
               Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
               nextActivity(profile);
        }
```

Comment: still having same issue

Comment: Is onSuccess getting called or not? If it is what values you are getting for accesstoken and profile? Also where you are initializing your intent "main"?

Comment: yes onSuccess is being called and profile is showing **null** value and accesstoken is showing **{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_friends, public_profile]}**
intent is initialized in nextActivity method, I missed writing it here.

Comment: It worked man thanks, but I still don't get it why it returns null profile initially even when it is going in onSuccess method.